# database independence in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have a simple WPF/EF Core 2.2.4 application that uses postgres.
I'm analyzing the possible strategies to migrate it on SQL Server.

In non ORM applications, it's quite common to limit the database-specific reference to the connection string togheter with providing a way to dynamically load the database driver (thinking of JDBC model). In that model you have to address the problem of writing SQL that works cross databases.

Here the problem of SQL writing, actually the major one, is solved right from the start. So I find it quite paradoxical that we sort of reintroduce database dependency in the form of helper methods.

My first question is about the DbContext. The OnConfiguring receives a DbContextOptionsBuilder that is used to pass Connection string. 
But in order to pass the connection string you use a database-specific method that is provided as an *extension method* by the database provider.
That is the `optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connstr)` in the following example. 
How should I address this in a database-independend application?

```
class MyDbContext: DbContext
{

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

    string connstr = 
            ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["MYAPP_PROD"].ConnectionString;

    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connstr);

    }

}
```

The second question is: how can I load the entire database package in a dynamic way, so that I can manage to configure it instead of harcoding it?
Actually I use NuGet to get the package:

```
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

Say that I want to use:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You haven't hard-coded anything - apart from putting the `UseNpgsql` call in the wrong class - it should be in the `Startup` class instead. You can call `UseNpgsql` or `UseSqlServer` as you like, based on a configuration setting, eg an environment variable. That's how .NET Core itself works when it checks the environment variable to decide if it's in Development or Production

Answer (score 1):

Use the strategy pattern to register the relevant database provider based on external configuration.

```
interface IDbProvider {
    bool AppliesTo(string providerName);
    DbContextOptions<T> LoadProvider<T>();
}
```

```
public class PostgresSqlProvider : IDbProvider {

    public bool AppliesTo(string providerName) {
        return providerName.Equals("Postgres");
    }

    public DbContextOptions<T> LoadProvider<T>() {
        //load provider.
    }
}
```

```
var providers = new [] {
    new PostgresSqlProvider()
};
var selectedDbProvider = ""; //Load from user input / config

var selectedProvider = providers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AppliesTo(selectedDbProvider));
if(selectedProvider == null) {
    throw new NotSupportedException($"Database provider {selectedDbProvider} is not supported.");
}

var options = selectedProvider.LoadProvider<DbContext>();
```

Comment: That pattern is already provided by ADO.NET and EF itself. That's what `UseSqlServer` method does - it injects the SQL Server provider to the application

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos isnt the question asking how to load the provider dynamically though? `UseSqlServer` will indeed inject SQLServer provider into the context but the question is asking how to dynamically inject a user selected provider thus the strategy pattern lets you switch between `UseSqlServer` & `UsePostgres`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so rather than `UseXServer()` is now `UseProvider(userSelection)`?

Comment: That's just an `if` or `switch` statement in `Startup.ConfigureServices`. There's no need for extra classes. The *real* problem is specifying the provider *inside* the context

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Correct but a strategy pattern follows the open close principle. Classes should be extensible not modifiable.

Comment: In this case it doesn't - it injects *outside* concerns in a class *designed* to ignore them. The context doesn't have to be modified to handle multiple providers. The problem is *already* solved by ` services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(` which already does the job of the provider you propose. All that's needed is specifying the `Action<DbContextBuilder>` method. This can easily come from a lookup table of actions if you want, eg a `Dictionary<string,Action<...>>` but frankly, a switch picking one of a few methods may be enough

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Im not fully understanding the issue you're proposing? Are you saying that this solution is just over engineered and that a `Dictionary<string, Action<T>>` would be better for its simplicity?

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is already covered by EF Core. Configuring providers should be done in [Startup.ConfigureServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#startupcs), using any of the [AddDbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContext__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder__Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_) methods that accept a builder action.

In the simplest case (dirtiest?), you can select providers based on a flag or a value that comes from the config system itself eg :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();

    var connString=Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext");  
    var useSqlServer=Configuration.GetSection("MyDbConfig").GetValue<bool>("UseSqlServer");
    services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>{
        if (useSqlServer)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connString);
        }
        else 
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(connString);
        }
    });
}
```

or

```
var provider=Configuration.GetSection("MyDbConfig").GetValue<ProviderEnum>("Provider");
services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>{
    switch (provider)
    {
        case ProviderEnum.SqlServer:
             options.UseSqlServer(connString);
             break;
        case ProviderEnum.Postgres :
             options.UseNpgsql(connString);
             break;
        ...
    }
});
```

That flag can come from configuration as well, eg from the command-line, environment variables, etc.

**Refactoring to .... lots**

*Extension method*

This code can be extracted to an extension method on `IServiceCollection`, similar to other contexts, eg:

```
public static ConfigureContexts(this IServiceCollection services,string connString, string provider)
{
    services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>{
        switch (provider)
        {
            case ProviderEnum.SqlServer:
                 options.UseSqlServer(connString);
                 break;
            case ProviderEnum.Postgres :
                 options.UseNpgsql(connString);
                 break;
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

and used :

```
var connString=Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext");  
var provider=Configuration.GetSection("MyDbConfig").GetValue<ProviderEnum>("Provider");
services.ConfigureContexts(provider,connString);
```

*Builder picker*

The builder, configuration patterns allow many variations that can handle complex scenarios. For example, we can pick a builder method in advance  :

```
var efBuilder= SelectBuilder(provider,connString);
services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(efBuilder);

...

Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> SelectBuilder(ProviderEnum provider,string connString)
{
    switch (provider)
    {
        case ProviderEnum.SqlServer:
           return ConfigureSql;
        case ProviderEnum.Postgres :
           return ConfigurePostgres;
    }

    void ConfigureSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connString);
    }

    void ConfigurePostgres(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseNpgSql(connString);
    }
}
```

In C# 8 this could be reduced to:

```
Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> SelectBuilder(ProviderEnum provider,string connString)
{
    return provider switch (provider) {
        ProviderEnum.SqlServer => ConfigureSql,
        ProviderEnum.Postgres => ConfigurePostgres
    };

    void ConfigureSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connString);
    }

    void ConfigurePostgres(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseNpgSql(connString);
    }
}
```

*Concrete config class*

Another possibility is to create a strongly-typed configuration class and have *it* provide the builder :

```
class MyDbConfig
{
    public ProviderEnum Provider {get;set;}
    ....
    public Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> SelectBuilder(string connString)
    {
        return provider switch (provider) {
            ProviderEnum.SqlServer => ConfigureSql,
            ProviderEnum.Postgres => ConfigurePostgres
        };

        void ConfigureSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connString);
        }

        void ConfigurePostgres(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseNpgSql(connString);
        }
    }

}
```

and use it :

```
var dbConfig=Configuration.Get<MyDbConfig>("MyDbConfig");
var efBuilder=dbCongig.SelectBuilder(connString);
services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(efBuilder);
```